# Matlab: How to compare the progressive value of a variable to it's previous best and reassign it to it's previous best?

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I've a piece of code to evaluate the performance of a variable in a loop such that we keep check of its progress and compare it with it's best value ever and assign it back to this best value if the newly assigned value is evaluated to be not better than the performance of this variable at its best value.

```
for (True) 

err = sum(Y*X'*w <=0);   %measure the performance of w for fixed X and Y variables.
err_best = sum(Y*X'*wbest <=0);  %measure the performance of w best
if(err <= err_best)              %if performance of newly assigned value of w is better than that of its career best wbest then update wbest with this newly identified best value.
    wbest = w;            %update the value of wbest if the w is evaluated to be better than the previous best wbest.
end
w = wbest;                 % wbest is updated to the best value evaluated thus far and assign to w this value.

% Code to change w value.

end
```

Please ignore the rest of the code as that is immaterial for this question. I would like to know how to retain the best of the values of the variable w and store it in wbest as the w variable goes through code that changes it over and over. As of now, this piece of code doesn't give the results as expected and the rest of the code doesn't need any change.

Comment: Assume you have initialized `w`=A and `wbest`=B outside the loop. By the end of first iteration, you would always have `w = wbest (== A or B)`. Thus in the second iteration, you will always have `err == err_best`, then again you will have `wbest = w (==A or B)`, then `w = wbest (==A or B)`. So your iteration just keeps looping but does nothing. Also you may want to reconsider your algorithm. "Assign it back to this best value" means you will simply go back to a previous computation step. This won't help unless your algorithm executes that step differently the second time.

Comment: if you want a really fast solution, we need a n example dataset with your desired output.

Comment: @MingjingZhang there is code to change w value which is not shown so in the second iteration it would have a different error.

Comment: Why are you doing w=wbest at the end? Does the new w depend on the old w? If it does, and the next w gives an err worse than the best, your algorithm will be stuck.

Comment: I got it resolved. Thanks to everyone who pointed out the redundancy of this piece of code. I deleted the last command and used wbest differently down the line so I got the results as intended.

I appreciate all.  The command w = wbest; has been pretty costly. special thanks to @MingjingZhang

Answer (score -1):

You can always append the best values in your `wbest` and use `wbest(end)` as the 'best until now' like:

```
for (True) 

err = sum(Y*X'*w <=0);   %measure the performance of w for fixed X and Y variables.
err_best = sum(Y*X'*wbest(end) <=0);  %measure the performance of w best
if(err <= err_best)              %if performance of newly assigned value of w is better than that of its career best wbest then update wbest with this newly identified best value.
    wbest = [wbest w];            %update the value of wbest if the w is evaluated to be better than the previous best wbest.
end
w = wbest(end);                 % wbest is updated to the best value evaluated thus far and assign to w this value.

% Code to change w value.

end
```

This will make sure you have a history of `wbest` when you break from your loop.

Comment: This approach doesn't solve the problem either. Thanks though.Could you rather point out if you see any mistake in the code attached in the question? Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't solve the problem" before downvoting on people trying to help you for free ? What's the shape of `w`

Comment: I never downvoted.

I get the same result with your approach as I had been getting using the code attached in the post. I'm more keen on knowing if there is anything wrong with my approach in the code.

Thanks.